# Output from .NET Core console app by docker logs

Tags: docker, logging, .net-core

Should I see console output (Console.WriteLine) from my .NET Core console app dockerized (linux image) by using docker logs command?

Comment: Yes you should see it

Comment: Logs don't show up because container main process is "tail -f /dev/null"

Answer (score 7):

Found out that in debug mode the app only writes to the debug output console. So if you run `docker logs` on a local debugging container there will be nothing. If you run the container in release mode then the logs will be present when running a `docker logs`

Answer (score 3):

Want to extend [@Cale's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49616838/534812) Answer.

Like he said:

- with VS-Debugging: Docker Logs do NOT work
- Building and Starting the image without VS: Docker Logs work

Let's look into the containers, to understand whats happening.

Basic knowledge: docker logs will be fed from the stdout and stderr of the process started by the defined entry-point. Defined via `Dockerfile` and/or `docker-compose.yml`.

## "regular docker usecase" after docker build, no Debugging

After building the image (without VS) an starting it via docker run, it looks like this.

```
$ docker build -t my-project:dev Dockerfile .

$ docker inspect -f '{{json .Config.Entrypoint}}' my-project:dev
["dotnet","MyProject.dll"]
```

The Entrypoint is our application, so docker will read the stdout and stderr of our application and create logs.

## Debug

Short:
docker-image entry-point is `tail -f /dev/null` -> no docker logs, never ever.
After the container is running w/o your app running, VS-Debug starts the application via `docker exec MyAppContainer 'sh -c vsdbg ...'` -> all output (stdout, stderr, debug) goes to VS

tldr;

Here it get's interesting ;)

VS Debug will create a container, which looks like this:

```
docker inspect -f '{{json .Config.Entrypoint}}' MyProjectName
["tail","-f","/dev/null"]
```

The allready mentioned `tail -f /dev/null` entrypoint.
Docker will read from this process > therefore nothing.
Actually our app isn't started at all via regular docker mechanics!

So how is out application debug sesseion started?
Let's connect to the image and take a look.

```
root@2e65795bcd7e:/app# pstree -p 0 -A -T -a
?,
 |-sh,1394 -c...
 |   `-vsdbg,1401 --interpreter=vscode
 |       `-dotnet,1414 --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/packages --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages /app/bin/Debug/net5.0/MyApp.dll
 `-tail,1 -f /dev/null
```

At the bottom is our entrypoint started `tail -f /dev/null`
And on top is a `sh -c vsdbg ... dotnet ... MyApp.dll`.
When you stop and start debugging you can see how this process disapears and reapears.

So VS does something like this:

```
docker exec MyAppContainer 'sh -c vsdbg --interpreter=vscode'
```

which in turn will launch your app as a child

```
dotnet --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/packages --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages /app/bin/Debug/net5.0/MyApp.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for this remark - I know this is a pretty old question.  I am running into this on a mac doing and on my windows box this never happens...Windows must be doing something differently

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can see logs written to stdout and stderr if you use the default logging driver.

> By default, docker logs shows the command’s STDOUT and STDERR.

[View logs for a container or service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/view_container_logs/)

Comment: This is strange, but I cannot see this output. If I'm running app with debugging, I can see output in VS Debug Console. If I'm running without debugging I can see output in VS Docker Console. But if I'm running app from docker command, I cannot see output

Comment: I should mention that this is Docker running on windows with linux as host system (as Hyper-V machine I think)

Comment: Can you post your dockerfile here?

Comment: This is my Dockerfile:    
    FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime
    ARG source
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerOutputTest.dll"]

Comment: What is the STDOUT version to be used for ASP.Net MVC Application?