# ASP.NET Core/.NET Core Console app logging in Docker container

Tags: visual-studio, docker, logging, asp.net-core, .net-core

How do I write log in .net core application running inside docker container so that log messages will show up in `docker logs <container-id>` alternatively in Kitematic UI?

I've tried almost everything but always end up with no logs from dotnet apps. All the others non-dotnet apps I have in containers like NODE.js, nginx, rabbitmq write logs with no problem.

Here is what I've already tried:

- console app (.NET Core) using `Console.WriteLine`
- ASP.NET Core app (default setup after using VS template with docker support) using ILogger interface
- using log4net inside console/ASP.NET Core app (logging actually works for example with RollingFileAppender) with ConsoleAppender

I couldn't find anyone experiencing the same problems (stackoverflow, google, github issues) so I assume I am missing something essential here.

### UPDATE 1:

This is my current setup:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Docker for Windows 17.12.0-ce
- docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a96
- running Linux containers

### UPDATE 2:

Example of working Dockerfile (NodeJS app)

```
FROM node:9-slim
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV NODE_PATH=/node_modules
ENV PATH=$PATH:/node_modules/.bin

COPY ./MyApp ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Example of NOT working Dockerfile (ASP.NET Core, generated by Visual Studio)

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY DockerLoggingTest2/DockerLoggingTest2.csproj DockerLoggingTest2/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/DockerLoggingTest2
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerLoggingTest2.dll"]
```

As you can see, there is nothing special about it. So the problem must be in .NET Core, since all the other types of application logs okay.

Comment: We use Serilog with the Console Logging activated

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029317/output-from-net-core-console-app-by-docker-logs

Comment: What Dockerfile are you using? if your container is not PID 1, the logs would neve be captured by Docker in the first place and explain your symptoms

Comment: @ChristianSauer I am using default dockerfile what is generated by visual studio when you create new application with docker support. It also uses docker-compose v3.

Comment: @ChristianSauer not sure how I can check the container's PID. I don't see it in `docker ps`

Comment: @RadekStromský Default Dockerfile and Docker Compose should be correct.
Can you test a new empty asp.net core project with makes a couple of WriteLines() and uses maybe Serilog + Console Logging?

Comment: @ChristianSauer That is exactly what I did. With clear console app with single WriteLine Hello World, and the same for ASP.NET Core app

Comment: I've just realized that only difference between those applications (working/not working) is, that I am running .NET apps from Visual Studio. So maybe the problem that Visual Studio breaks things as usual ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as I suspected. Visual Studio is the man in the middle that swallows all the log messages. I think it has something to do with yaml overrides in docker-compose command that Visual Studio calls to probably enable all the debugging features.

```
docker-compose  -f "docker-compose.yml" -f "docker-compose.override.yml" -f "obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose2788718473649893946 up -d --force-recreate --remove-orphans
```

It looks like following file `obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml` is responsible for the behaviour I am experiencing. When I run this command without it, everything work as expected.

Thank you all for the brainstorming that led to this answer.

Comment: Ahhh you should have told us that you want to debug. Yes, VS redirects all Output to it's own output log. This does not happen in production scenarios

Comment: I didn't want to debug, but Visual Studio by default runs in debug mode and I didn't realized that could possibly do any harm. My bad. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Adding the following to appsettings.json

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "IncludeScopes": true
    }
  }
```

be sure your project is configured to copy your appsettings, inside of YourProject.csproj ensure

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I then added the config to the logging service.

```
            services.AddLogging(builder =>
                builder
                    .AddDebug()
                    .AddConsole()
                    .AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
                    .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information)
            );
```

hope this helps

Comment: I know it's a stupid question, but where does `configuration` come from? -- The default template doesn't have that variable. (I know there are a hundred ways to get it, but I'm guessing there's a correct way to get it, for docker services, in this specific circumstance, and I don't know what that is.)

Comment: FYI, in the latest C# "Worker Service" template I just made the config changes from this answer, (no code changes), and now logs show up both in the docker app and in the Visual Studio output window (using CTRL+F5, not debugging... so that's neat)!

Comment: configuration should be Configuration