# Execute compiled .NetCore console in docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I wrote this small .net core app that backup and transfer mysql database from a server to a dockerized app. However, when I put it in docker and try to run it nothing happens. If there is an error in the app it should console.writeline the error message but nothing.

```
FROM mysql:5.7.34
COPY ./dbmover /tmp/dbmover
WORKDIR /tmp/dbmover
EXPOSE 3306
```

As you already figured out my released .net core app is contained in the dbmover folder and copied on the docker container.

Now if I connect to the container shell and execute the app I get no output of it. I run ./myapp.exe

There are my release settings for my app.
[image: There are my release settings for my app.]

Note that this application is not meant to be dockerized it is just a tool to help build the container.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your docker file does not seem to bring in dotnet only mysql?

Comment: I'll try to install dotnet but I guessed that since I used the self contained option I wouldn't need to do that ?

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029317/output-from-net-core-console-app-by-docker-logs) might also help.

Comment: installed dotnet runtime through the bash but no luck

Comment: Thanks @AliK I didn't see anything on the logs related to the apps so far. And when I execute the app it does not seems to write on logs. I'll try to find more from the question you sent me.

Answer (score 1):

SO I didn't noticed at first but I was publishing with visual studio instead of the command line tool. Once it is done publishing it is ginving you the path of the publish. What I ddin't notive is that it was the parent folder of the publishing folder which was linux-x64 folder. Once I took the linux-x64 subfolder instead of the main one it started working.